# Selecting records with dates across years in Access 2007

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2007

I'm saving records in an Access 2007 database into a simple 2-column table, and generating reports from it using this query:

```
sql = "SELECT 
        OrderDate AS `Order Date and Time`, 
        Items AS `Ordered Items` 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')  
       >= Format(#" + startDate.Value.Date + "#,'mm/dd/yyyy') 
      AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')
       <= Format(#" + endDate.Value.Date + "#,'mm/dd/yyyy')
    ORDER BY OrderDate"
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are datePicker objects in VB.2010.

Reports are generated as expected when the `startDate` and `endDate` are within the same year. So for example if I check for orders between 18th Nov and 27th Dec, I get the expected results. But if I go, say from Nov 1 2012 to Jan 8 2013, it doesn't show up any records, even though there are records in all of those months (Nov, Dec and Jan).

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the actual dates in your query, not formatted dates.  Something like:

```
SELECT OrderDate, Items 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN #startDate.Value.Date# AND #endDate.Value.Date# 
ORDER BY OrderDate;
```

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/sql-between.html

Alternatively, if you want to keep your original query, try changing the formatting of the dates so that the year is most significant, followed by the month and the day, thusly:

```
SELECT OrderDate AS `Order Date and Time`, Items AS `Ordered Items` 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Format(Orders.OrderDate,'yyyy/mm/dd') >= Format(#" + startDate.Value.Date + "#,'yyyy/mm/dd') 
AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'yyyy/mm/dd') <= Format(#" + endDate.Value.Date + "#,'yyyy/mm/dd') 
ORDER BY OrderDate;
```

Comment: why thank you! I couldn't put the actual dates since I'm getting them from a DatePicker object in VB.2010, but I used your second snippet and it worked! But why? I think it's quite ridiculous that we should have to do that for it to work.

Comment: Your first example works because "11/18/2012" is less than "12/27/2012".  Your second example doesn't work because "11/01/2012" is greater than "01/08/2013".  Remember, you're comparing strings here, not dates.  My change works because "2012/11/01" is less than "2013/01/08"

Comment: Wow I never realized that! Are you aware of any function in this context for date comparison?

Comment: I'm used to doing it the first way I described in my answer.  The `#` signs convert it into an *actual date value*, so that it can be properly compared, although you may not need the `#` if `.Date` is returning actual date values already.

Comment: As an aside for future readers, if you are working in VBA, it is best to use ampersand (&), not plus (+) as the concatenator due to the way + works with null in VBA.